# Implementing a queue using an existing implementation of a linked list: Bad File Number error

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, queue

I have been given some existing C code (a header file and some source code) for an implementation of a linked list and have been given a task to use that to implement a queue.

Here is part of the header file I have been given with relevant function descriptions:

```
/* List is a pointer to a list_t struct */
typedef struct list_t* List;

struct list_t {
    void *data;
    List next;
};

/* Pushes data as the new head of list. May be used to create a new list:
 * new_list = push(NULL, data) */
extern List push(List list, void *data);

/* Pop the head off the list */
extern void *pop(List *list);

/* Return the length of the list */
extern int len(List list);

/* Returns a reversed copy of list */
List reverse(List list);

/* Prepend data to list and update list */
extern List prepend(List *list, void *data);

/* Append l1 to the end of l2 */
void append(List l1, List *l2);

/* Inserts data into the tail of list */
void insert(void *data, List *list);

/* Inserts data into the tail of list or position equal to the next element     */
void insert_by(bool (*eq)(void *data, void *node), void *data, List *list);

/* Inserts data into the tail of list. Returns true if sucessful,
 * false if it finds an element already equal to data */
bool insert_if(bool (*eq)(void *data, void *node), void *data, List *list);

/* Returns the node equal to aim in list, returns NULL if not found */
extern List find(bool (*eq)(void *aim, void *node), void *aim, List list);

/* Removes and returns the element equal to aim in list,
 * returns NULL if not found */
extern void *del(bool (*eq)(void *aim, void *node), void *aim, List *list);

/* Returns a new list that passes the predicate p */
List filter(bool (*p)(void *data), List list);

/* Print list to f by applying print to each node that is not NULL */
extern void print_list(void (*print)(FILE *f, void *data), FILE *f, List node);

/* Free the memory allocated to each list node */
extern void free_list(List node);
```

I know that in order to implement a queue, I need at minimum two functions, `enqueue()` and `dequeue()`. I went ahead and created my own header file with these functions and a typedef for the queue, using the List type from the above header file:

```
//Queue.h
#include "list.h"

typedef List Queue;

//Add item to queue...
void enqueue(Queue q, void *data);

//removes and returns an item from the queue...
void dequeue(Queue *q);
```

I then went ahead and implemented the source code in `queue.c`. I only implemented `enqueue` for now since I wanted to make sure that it worked before moving on:

```
#include "queue.h"

void enqueue(Queue q, void *data){
    if (q == NULL){
        q = push(q, data);
    }
    else {
        insert(data, &q);
    }
}
```

Really simple, I know. I planned to use the following file, `main.c` to test the queue:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "queue.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    Queue q = NULL;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){ enqueue(q, &i); } //one line for brevity
    return 0;
}
```

At this point I didn't expect to see any output when I ran `main.c`, all I expected was for the program to run with no errors and then stop. Everything compiled fine, however when I ran `main.c` all I got was:

```
sh: ./main.exe: bad file number
```

What does this mean and can anybody pinpoint what could be causing this problem?

EDIT: Source code was compiled as such:

```
gcc -c list.c
gcc -c queue.c
gcc -c main.c -o main.exe
```

Comment: can you please compile like this--> gcc list.c queue.c main.c -o main.exe

Answer (score 0):

This is not exclusively about a C programming problem but about the compiler commande not invoked correctly.

Your compile commands are incomplete.

Use this:

```
gcc -c list.c
gcc -c queue.c
gcc -c main.c
gcc list.o main.o queue.o -o main.exe
./main.exe
```

Explanation:

```
gcc -c list.c                           produces list.o
gcc -c queue.c                          produces queue.o
gcc -c main.c                           produces main.o
gcc list.o main.o queue.o -o main.exe   invokes the linker that links the .o files
                                        together producing main.exe

./main.exe                              run the program
```

There may be other programming related issues in your C code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `enqueue` function breaks the contract of the `push` method.

The `push`method returns the new head.

You would need:

```
Queue enqueue(Queue q, void *data){
    return push(q, data);
}
```

And in your call:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){ 
    q = enqueue(q, &i); 
}
```

Note, however that this will push the same pointer every iteration. If you change `i` you will change the value of every node in the Queue. This is probably not what you want!

Also note that queueing the adress of a local (auto) variable is probably a bad thing and can lead to stack problems when the variable goes out of scope. (In your case `i` is declared in `main`, so it won't go out of scope until the program ends.)

Comment: I went ahead and changed the `enqueue` function but it still doesn't add elements to the queue. Can you see the issue?

Comment: When the first element is added the head of the queses changes from `NULL` to the first Queue item. You need to update the queue pointer somehow. I suggested that you return the new address, but you haven't done so, so in `main` the value of `q` never changes from the initial `NULL` value.